# Download image from URL and add to scrollview subviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I want to when my item have gallery get image urls and create imageView with url data and add this image view to scroll view subviews, and scroll between scroll view subviews. my imageView array have 6 imageView, but image view image is empty, my scroll view paging work well but just one image show in scroll view other image view image is white background. there is my code.

in get data from webService create array of url and then call getImageData mehtod

```
func getImageData() {

  self.defaultImage.isHidden = true
  self.scrollView.isHidden = false
  scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
  scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
  scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
  scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
  self.scrollView.willRemoveSubview(defaultImage)
  for i in gallaryURL {
      self.downloadImage(string: i)      
  }
  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 

}

func downloadImage(string: String)  {

  let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: string)!
  // Start background thread so that image loading does not make app unresponsive
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
  let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:self.scrollWith!*2, y:0,width:self.scrollWith!, height:self.scrollHeight!))
  myImageView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
  let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
  myImageView.image = image
   // When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.allImage.append(myImageView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.frame.width * 4, height:self.scrollView.frame.height)
        }
    }

func moveToNextPage() {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
    let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * 4
    let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x
    var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth
    if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth{
        slideToX = 0
    }
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x:slideToX, y:0, width:pageWidth, height:self.scrollView.frame.height), animated: true)
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: can yu attach your project

Comment: This is a very big project and this small part of it, I shall make an example of this section.

Comment: ok attach the sample project

Comment: @anbu.Karthik sample project link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/savxdth6cv6y41s/sampleScroll.xcodeproj.zip?dl=0

Comment: your project was not attached properly check once

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2euxf66cdvsdtk0/sampleScroll.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at this line:

```
let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:self.scrollWith!*2, y:0,width:self.scrollWith!, height:self.scrollHeight!))
```

You make all of ImageView is the same potsition x, they are overlapping the position `self.scrollWith!*2`.

You can add a parameter named somthing like `index` or `position` in your `downloadImage` function like the following:

```
func downloadImage(string: String, index: Int) {

    let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: string)!
    // Start background thread so that image loading does not make app unresponsive
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!

    let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:self.scrollWith!*index, y:0,width:self.scrollWith!, height:self.scrollHeight!))
    myImageView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
    myImageView.image = image

    // When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.allImage.append(myImageView)

        self.scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)


        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.frame.width * 4, height:self.scrollView.frame.height)

    }
}
```

And then you can use the for loop like the following:

```
func getImageData() {

    self.defaultImage.isHidden = true
    self.scrollView.isHidden = false
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.willRemoveSubview(defaultImage)

    for i in 0..<gallaryURL.count {

        self.downloadImage(string: gallaryURL[i], index: i)

    }

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Hope the solution can be work for you.

Comment: This made it better، but basically the problem is not solved. When there are  5 pictures، it shows just 4 out of 5 and I can not scroll down to see the last one.

Comment: Your sample code have somthing error like response json is 0,   
but you use this at `line 125` in `ScrollPagingViewController.swift`:  
`let arrJSON = response.result as! [String:Any]`
Please provide correct sample